# Convert to Time Format Only

Tags: sql

I hv the following table which I hv converted:-

[image]

by using the following SQL command:-

[image]

How can I convert it to this format:-

[image]

I believe it has something to do with the "convert(datetime, '7:30:00',120)".

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server? If so, what version? For 2008 or later, the obvious is `CONVERT(time,'07:30:00')`

Comment: It is SQL Server 2008. Tried that convert(time,'07:30:30') but prompted with 'Operand type clash: int is incompatible with time'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CONVERT(time,'07:30:00')` instead - but you also need to come up with a more appropriate default value for the `ELSE` clause of your `CASE` expression, maybe '00:00:00'? `0` isn't a time.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I need to tweak it to '00:00:00' under ELSE clause. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108) as TimeIn
```

Comment: why use GETDATE ? I'm inserting a fixed time ie 7:30 or 8:30 etc.

Comment: I gave just a sample. You can modify it according to your requirements.